# Scythe: Opening Moves Book?

Tags: openings, scythe

Would it be feasible to create an opening book for Scythe, analogously to chess openings?

- It would have 7 factions x 7 starting boards = 49 parts, which would be further subdivided depending on game conditions and opponent replies
- It could feature an agreed-upon shorthand notation and simplified board maps
- It would be a community effort, so be continuously updated and contain ratings
- It could also feature something like chess' endgame quizzes, like "here's a board at a given move, win in 2 moves by getting 40 coins (expansion rules)".

Are there any existing frameworks or tools that can help with this?

Comment: As a 1-5 player game an opening moves book would get a lot more complicated for each additional player that is playing. In chess (and other similar games) there is only 1 opponent to worry about but when you have multiple opponents a response move becomes more complicated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 7x7 = 49.

Comment: There is one here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OJiFyrhkue3zMUNGgZkCrETycGNog2mgS5_s4mKmIqA/edit

Not sure how competitive it is.